# Improving performances of nodejs and MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance

I'm rewriting a php application in nodejs.

I'm facing an issue with performances when querying a mysql database.

I'm executing the following query:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id
FROM stock
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM stock
  WHERE warehouse = 1
) ORDER BY id
FOR UPDATE;

DELETE FROM stock WHERE warehouse = 1;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/28718734728601.csv'
INTO TABLE stock FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
(sku, qty, warehouse);

COMMIT;
```

Running it in PHP using PDO it takes around 3 seconds.
Running it in Nodejs using [mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) or [mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) it takes around 5 seconds.

The query is locking rows on the `stock` table and a 2/3 seconds lock is ok, but 5 or more is too much in my context.

Does anyone have any suggestion/idea on how to improve performances for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use that subquery in the SELECT.  It is (1) inefficient, and (2) unnecessary.
- Don't even have the SELECT -- You are not getting any values from it, and the DELETE will lock the rows promptly anyway.

How many rows are in warehouse #1?  Is the LOAD reloading all the #1 values?

Comment: HI Rick, thanks for the answer. I'll try the `SELECT` without the subquery, you are right about it. About the second point: I need and exclusive lock (`SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`) on the rows of the stock table because other transactions (also using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`) will try to lock those rows as well, and I want them to wait that my operation is done.

Comment: just tried to use `SELECT id FROM stock WHERE warehouse = 1 ORDER BY id FOR UPDATE;`.
This produces a deadlock when run concurrently to queries that are locking rows by `id` ie: `SELECT id FROM stock WHERE id IN (...) ORDER BY id FOR UPDATE;`.
The two queries are not using the same index when scanning the table.

Comment: The `DELETE` locks the rows.

Comment: Have the application sort the ids before building the `SELECT`.  Then you don't need the `ORDER BY`.